# i want remove row has one value duplicated with other row (resultSet)

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to remove rows has duplicate value in specific column

my Query return data like this:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | First | exp1 |
| 2 | text2 | Second | exp2 |
| 3 | text3 | third | exp3 |
| 4 | text4 | third | exp4 |

I want it like this:

| Column1 | Column1 | Column1 | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | First | exp1 |
| 2 | text2 | Second | exp2 |
| 3 | text3 | third | exp3 |

---

**MY QUERY** VALUE DUPLICATE IS t2.numeroLot

````
select t2.nomClient,t2.numeroTlf,t2.numeroLot,t2.nature,t2.prixPaiement,t1.paym,t1.payer from ((select dossier.refDossier, (Paiement.prixPaiement SUM(CONVERT(float,PaiementDeclare.montant))) as paym,SUM(CONVERT(float,PaiementDeclare.montant)) as payer from payment 
left join dossier on dossier.idPaiement = payment.idPaiement left join PaiementDeclare on PaiementDeclare.idPaiement = Paiement.idPaiement group by  Paiement.prixPaiement,dossier.refDossier) 
left join (select dossier.refDossier,client.nomClient,client.numeroTlf,lot.numeroLot,lot.nature, Paiement.prixPaiement from dossier 
left Join dossierClient on dossierClient.idDossier = dossier.idDossier 
left join client on client.idClient = dossierClient.idClient 
left join dossierLot on dossierLot.idDossier = dossier.idDossier 
left join lot on lot.idLot = dossierLot.idLot   
left join Paiement on Paiement.idPaiement = dossier.idPaiement  
left join PaiementDeclare on PaiementDeclare.idPaiement = Paiement.idPaiement
group by prixPaiement,dossier.refDossier,client.nomClient,numeroTlf,lot.numeroLot,lot.nature) t2
on t2.refDossier = t1.refDossier)  
where t1.refDossier is not null```
````

Comment: Please please please format that SQL. When you write formatting is paramount to making it easily readable, not just for others but yourself as well. That code is impossible to read easily.

Comment: "OK", @Larnu Sorry

Comment: Again, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want (the first one of each group). Then filtering out is easy.

Your query could take the form:

```
select *
from (
  select
    row_number() over(partition by t2.numeroLot order by t2.nomClient) as rn,
    -- rest of your big query here...
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: "thanks", big Query hhh